# LDAP search query not working?

Tags: php, search, ldap

Trying to search for information about a person in a directory with `LDAP`. everything else works except this search string but no one can figure out what is wrong.

The result just comes up with an empty set despite that it returns values in bash.

```
$result = ldap_search(
    $ds, 
    $base_domain, 
    '(CN=user)'
) or die("error in search");



<?php
$DEBUGGING = True;
if($DEBUGGING)
{
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
}



$server = 'ldaps://ds.cisco.com';
#$port = 639;
$port = 636;


$ds=ldap_connect($server, $port);
echo "connect result is " . $ds . "<br />";

if ($ds)
{

    $r = ldap_bind($ds, $username, $password);
    echo "Bind result is " . $r . "<br />";



    $base_domain = 'OU=Standard,OU=Cisco Groups,DC=cisco,DC=com';
    #$base_domain = 'dc=cisco,dc=com';
    #$base_domain = 'OU=Employees,OU=Cisco Groups,DC=cisco,DC=com';
    #$result = ldap_search($ds, $base_domain, '(&(CN=selyons))') or die ("error in search");
    #$result = ldap_search($ds, $base_domain, '(&(membersOf=CN=it-puppet-masters,OU=Standard,OU=Cisco Groups,DC=cisco,DC=com)(sAMAccountName=*))') or die ("error in search");

    $result = ldap_search($ds, $base_domain, '(CN=user)') or die("error in search");

    echo "SEARCHING" . "<br />";


    #while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM))
    #{
        #print_r($row);
        #print($row[0]);
    #}

    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $result);



    #$arraystring = print_r($info, true);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($info);
    echo "</pre>";
    #echo $arraystring;
    #print_r($info[699][2][0]);
    #print_r($info[699][2][1]);
    #print_r($info[699][2][2]);
    #print_r($info[699][2][3]);
    #print_r($info[699][2][4]);

    #print_r($info[699][2]);
    #print_r($info[699]);
    #$members = $info[0]["member"];
    #echo $members;

    #for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
    #{
        #print_r($info[699]);
    #}
}


?>
```

Comment: Define "does not work". Is there an error? Are any any search results returned in the search result? What do you mean "search string"? Doe you mean the filter?

Comment: I mean this query. It returns nothing just an empty set

Comment: The search parameters provided match no entries, then.

Comment: But when the same search query is done in bash it returns entries

Comment: Then the code is not sending the same search parameters as `ldapsearch`. What is actually transmitted to the server by the code?

Comment: i edited the post to include all the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at the container `OU=Standard,OU=Cisco Groups,DC=cisco,DC=com` for an object where `CN=user` is true.  Perhaps you meant `(objectClass=user)` or do you really expect to have an object whose `CN` attribute is set to `user`?

That seems lightly implausible.  You might be thinking about the AD default setup, where the Users container is actually a container and thus `cn=Users` and not `ou=Users` as you might have otherwise expected (nor `dc=Users`).